# Deploy SPFx webpart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to deploy my webpart developed with SPFx in my site on SharePoint 2013  farm. 
I followed this tutorials :

- http://jenkinsblogs.com/2016/10/04/deploy-spfx-client-side-web-part-to-a-sharepoint-library/
- https://blog.sprider.org/2016/08/31/package-and-deploy-sharepoint-framework-webpart/

But I failed. So my question is : is it really possible to deploy SPFx solutions on SharePoint 2013 ? Maybe you will have tutorials to recommend to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No its not possible to use/deploy SPFx in SP 2013 on Premises.

Its not supported in any way.

Its only supported in SharePoint online right now and in SP 2016 On Premise sometime later this year.

Also, reference link - [SharePoint Framework webinar Q&A follow-up. Part 1 – SharePoint Framework](https://rencore.com/blog/sharepoint-framework-webinar-qa-follow-part-1-sharepoint-framework)